# Почему валится unittest тест? AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'true'

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, импорт

Имеется модуль под названием unit,
в нем определена функция def get_formated

```
def get_formated(first, midle, last=''):
    if last:

          full_name=first+' ' + midle + ' ' + last
    else:
        full_name=first+' '+last

    return full_name.title()
```

Сам тест в модуле testirovanie

```
from unit import get_formated
import unittest

class UTestFigny(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_ingfigny(self):
        fomatedName=get_formated('жаклин','кенеди',)
        self.assertEqual(fomatedName,'Жаклин Кенеди')


unittest.main()
```

Тест фейлится с сообщениями

```
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: testirovanie (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'testirovanie'

======================================================================
ERROR: true (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'true'
```

Не могу понять причину.

Используется Питон 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

В testirovanie должно быть

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

`__name__` может принимать два значения в зависимости от ситуации. Если модуль импортируется, то оно равно имени модуля. Если модуль исполняется напрямую, оно равно `__main__`.

У меня в [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) (стандартная базовая IDE от python) приведенный Вами код работает. В более же навороченной сторонней IDE выдает похожие Вашим ошибки. Очевидно, некоторые IDE по-своему обрабатывают файлы и требуют дополнительных уточнений в коде.

Кроме того, именно такая конструкция [предлагается официально](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example).

Comment: Добавил как вы и сказали. Все заработало, но проверил в дебаге значение атрибута  __name___ и оно оказалось равно "testirovanie". Как так ? Все работает но __name__  !==" __main__"

Comment: @RVG дополнил ответ

Comment: @RVG: `__name__` это имя модуля. Если модуль выполняется напрямую как скрипт, то `__name__ == '__main__'`. Ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что `unittest.main()` функция ожидает, что она внутри скрипта выполняется, а не во время импорта (`import testirovanie`). IDE может импортировать модуль для своих нужд—без `if __name__ == '__main__'` защиты, может неожиданный код выполниться.